# Allow import/export functions for super users only

Tags: django, import, export, django-import-export

I would like to allow the import/export functions for superusers only. How can this be achieved?

I managed to hide the import/export buttons through custom css. But I also would like to disable the corresponding function calls:

http://localhost:9012/admin/persons/person/import/
http://localhost:9012/admin/persons/person/export/

Comment: inside the export/import function just check if user is superuser else return False

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a function based view you can use the user_passes_test decorator to control which users will be able to use the view. To require the user is a superuser you can do this

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Or if you are using a class based view you can use the UserPassesTestMixin like this

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin

class MyView(UserPassesTestMixin, View):

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.is_superuser
```

Docs link:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test

Comment: Hi, there's a typo. `from django.contrib.auth.decotators` - it's decoRators. cheers

Comment: Thanks, fixed that